# Characters omitted while doing PRINT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am debugging a stored procedure which has lot of variables containing long SQL queries. I'm trying to print out these variables to get the exact underlying queries and have written a small code for it. Code is below.

```
DECLARE @Counter INT
SET @Counter = 0
DECLARE @TotalPrints INT
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(@FinalQuery, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
SET @TotalPrints = (LEN(@FinalQuery) / 8000) + 1
WHILE @Counter < @TotalPrints 
BEGIN
    PRINT SUBSTRING(@FinalQuery, (@Counter*8000)+1, 8000)
    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
END
```

The result which I get has characters omitted. Can someone please help me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: 4000 max for unicode. Why don't you just `SELECT @FinalQuery`

Comment: Because @FinalQuery is too big. And I read that PRINT can only handle max of 8000 chars. Thats why limited to that number. Will check if 4000 works

Comment: What, you can select whatever you want including `varchar(max)`?

Comment: Yeah but SELECT '@FinalQuery' is only displaying partial query (till some 43K characters). The actual length of '@FinalQuery' is much more than that. Thats why I had to find some other way

Comment: So, I am doing this all in SSMS if thats what you were asking. For Batch Size, what that is. Can you please guide me how to check that

Comment: Also, that reducing char to 4000 worked. Thank you! Can you put that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/print-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks):

> **Remarks**
>
> A message string can be up to 8,000 characters long if it is a non-Unicode string, and 4,000 characters long if it is a Unicode string. Longer strings are truncated. The varchar(max) and nvarchar(max) data types are truncated to data types that are no larger than varchar(8000) and nvarchar(4000).

If you've got Unicode `NVARCHAR` the maximum size is 4000